# The hidden 'Order' column in Tasks list not being migrated

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, tasks, sharepointmigrationtool

So for classic Tasks list, you are able to manual sort and indent items. This sorting is persistent and not personal. List View sorting is set to None.

[image: Manual Sort Buttons]

Performing a migration using SP Migration Tool from SP2013 to SPO, classic task list functionality is still fully available.

- Manual indent of items is migration
- Manual sort order of items is NOT migrated (it defaults to sorting by list ID)

I have found a hidden 'Order' column which isn't visable anywhere other than opening another column settings on the list and changing the URL to &Field=Order

- this Order column is not part of any content type or visible via SPD
- this column is present in the migrated list, but it not populated with data from the source

Anyone know any more about this column, can I extract data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I currently cannot verify the migration part of the process but you can try to unhide the Order field and then start a new migration.
The following PowerShell instructions allow you to unhide the Order field (remember to open SharePoint Management Shell with "Run as administrator" option).

```
$web = get-spweb http://win-c7to3h3n5cl/
$list = $web.Lists["WorkTasks"]
$field = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Order")
$type = $field.GetType()
$mi = $type.GetMethod("SetFieldBoolValue",
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]$([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance))
$mi.Invoke($field, @("CanToggleHidden",$true))
$field.Hidden=$false
$field.Update()
```

I found the script [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/450f8e75-425a-465e-933c-50de01a57ccd/powershell-how-to-unhide-a-hidden-site-column?forum=sharepointadminprevious)
and [here](https://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/unhide-a-hidden-spfield-using-powershell/)

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try thanks